# Unable to mount DVD - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, dvd

I seldom use the DVD drive and this a 5 year old laptop. Today I load the DVD and it just keeps spinning but nothing mounts. After it spins and stops I checked:

`dmesg | grep sr0`

> [    1.738204] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw
>   xa/form2 cdda tray [    1.738551] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0

I tried to manually mount with

`sudo mount /dev/sr0`

`sudo mount /dev/cdrom`

Then I checked:

`mount | grep "/dev/sr"`

It shows nothing.

The DVD is good and readable on my Windows machine.

Any ideas on how I can get it working?

Comment: Did you run `mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom` ?

Comment: Is it a DVD movie film or just data media? Are other disks mounted well in your system?

Comment: Its just data that I had backed up from the same laptop. I have just an internal HDD which is mounted and working.

Comment: Commands that you mentioned "`sudo mount /dev/sr0`" do not seem good for me until they have a place where to mount to. So what about running `mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/`?

Comment: sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/ returns
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't mount movie DVDs, and was having this error:

```
~$ dmesg | grep sr0
VFS: busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sr0
```

The solution that worked for me was to edit `/etc/fstab` which I found in a [mail-thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1891405.html).

So, as described there, I edited the file, adding in the end the following line:

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

and then I had to restart, since `fstab` is loaded on system start.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any message after `mount /dev/sr0` or `mount /dev/cdrom`?

I got something like: `mount: can't find /dev/sr0 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

Here is a quick example on my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. I mount the DVD to /mnt

```
$ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
$ cd /mnt/
$ ls
autorun.inf  casper  EFI      isolinux    pics  preseed             ubuntu
boot         dists   install  md5sum.txt  pool  README.diskdefines  wubi.exe'
```

Comment: Yes, I also got the same message and I have already tried to manually mount to mnt. But when I try that I get 
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
OR 
mount: /dev/sr0 already mounted or /mnt/ busy
Mostly it is the first message.

Comment: Can you try some other DVDs/CDs? Jsut want to make sure it's not a disk compatibility issue.

Comment: Same with every DVD that I try

Comment: the mount points (/media/cdrom nodes must exist and an appropriate line in the fstab file otherwise the user cannot mount them